# Maven Repository for eclipse 3.6 (or higher) plugins dependencies

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, swt

is there a stable maven  repository for eclipse 3.6 (or hiegher) plugins ? i've founded repo1.maven.org but this one includes only old versions

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MT4E](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Maven_Tools_4_Eclipse) to convert Eclipse bundles into Maven artifacts yourself.

Comment: You mean convert Eclipse Bundles into Maven Artifacts

Comment: It's an interesting solution

Answer (score 0):

I know there's this one:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>swt-repo</id>
        <url>https://swt-repo.googlecode.com/svn/repo/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

that links to the swt plugin, Not 100% on it having 'all' plugins though, likely they're a bit scattered around.